# Starting a web application with coded UI tests in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications, coded-ui-tests

I have a solution with a web application and test project. The test application has coded ui tests of the web application. How can I get the web application to start up when the tests execute?

I've tried

- adding a TestSetup method to start the web server via System.Diagnostics.Process. I don't like this because it seems clunky and the coded ui tests don't lend themselves to inheritance real well
- adding a setup script in the testsettings to start the web server (same command line) via a batch file. However the batch file never exits and eventually times out. I've tried starting the web server via the start command, but that didn't work -- it works great when you run it from the command line, but not from the testsettings setup script.

I've thought about maybe just running IIS in the background and pointing it to a specific folder. Then deploy the web application to that folder. And let the test project test against IIS.

This seems like a lot of work though. There's got to be an easier way. I want to do this on several developer's machine and also on the TFS build machine via scheduled or continuous integration.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It'd also be nice to know how to get the URL from the test code.

Answer (score 0):

I configure the web project (in the project properties) to be hosted on IIS. Its just 3 or 4 clicks away. It will prompt to create a virtual application. After that, build and run your project and it will be permanently hosted on IIS. So you can start Coded UI tests without manually starting the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what Gerardo Grignoli suggested and just host the site in IIS so that it's always on.

You could also just start the web project (Without Debugging if you want to debug your tests) and then run/debug the tests.  In your tests, just use BrowserWindow.Launch("localhost:appPort/whateverPageToStartOn");  just fill in the port instead of appPort based on your IIS express settings.

In regards to running it on the TFS build machine, that seems like probably a questionable thing to do.  You can test the deployed site (dev, test, prod, whatever) from a testing lab.  Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) is one of the products that can do this.